Getting multiple variables from the output of docker exec command in a bash script?
I would like to execute a script on a host machine (script_on_host.sh), which then reaches inside a docker container in order to grab some data using a second script (script_in_container.sh). The data is only available inside the container, and not from the host directly, hence the reason for doing it this way.
I am having trouble passing data between the two scripts. I tried the following:
script_in_container.sh
#!/bin/bash

x=1
y=2
z=6.3
echo $x
echo $y
echo $z

script_on_host.sh
#!/bin/bash

results=$(docker exec mycontainer './script_in_container.sh')
X=$results(1)
Y=$results(2)
Z=$results(3)

But it throws an error. Can someone help me with this? Is there a nice or more standard way to go about passing variables in this way? I feel like I'm maybe doing something a little clumsily here, by using echo to print multiple lines from the container script.

Where did you get the idea that $results(1) is the way to refer to the first word of $results? If $results were an array, it would use [] as the way to index it, and indexes start at 0.

@Barmar this is true. I guess its because I don't exclusively work with bash and am relatively new to it. Getting confused with the () and zero-indexing is due to me switching between many different languages, each with different syntax and conventions. However, these two mistakes on my part were not the main cause for my attempt here failing.

You can use sed, like this:
#!/bin/bash

results=$(docker exec mycontainer './script_in_container.sh')
X=$(echo "$results" |sed '1q;d')
Y=$(echo "$results" |sed '2q;d')
Z=$(echo "$results" |sed '3q;d')

The sed expression is actually two commands:

1q is a command to match the first line and quit
; is a command separator
d deletes the current line.

In the case of reading the first line the d is kind of redundant since sed will quit after it prints line 1 anyway but for other lines the d is necessary to delete any lines that do not match your first command.

Don't you need the double quotes somewhere here?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk you are right. I've updated my answer.

Thanks, can you explain what the "1q;d" syntax is doing exactly?

The big disadvantage of this method is that you need to run sed for all lines, either manually or in a loop and what's worse manually control all variable names.

You could use readarray to build an array of results delimited by newline.
readarray -t results < <(docker exec mycontainer './script_in_container.sh')
x=${results[0]}
y=${results[1]}
z=${results[2]}


The simplest solution would be to use set -- to assign variables
from the docker container to the positional parameters  like
this:
#!/bin/bash

results=$(docker exec mycontainer './script_in_container.sh')

saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
set -- $results
IFS=$saveIFS

echo result 1: "$1"
echo result 2: "$2"
echo result 3: "$3"


This is probably the best way to do and it also POSIX compatible.

Caveat: this may change an unset IFS to an empty IFS, which has different semantics.

Just set IFS so: "IFS=$'\n'" (I prefer "IFS=$'\012' for some reason) and then "unset IFS". IFS will return to its default value.

@jesse_b how is this answer simpler than your readarray answer (which is very similar to a question that I recently asked about returning multiple values from a call to ssh)?

@RonJohn it's not more simple but it is more portable.  readarray only works in bash and only bash 4.0 and later at that, so it wouldn't work on the bash that ships with macos for example.

@Arkadiusz How does this work exactly? I don't understand how the line "set -- $results" works. As I understand it, the -- just means "what follows are not options for the command". So doesn't do much. But why does this set command by default split the array into variables $1,$2,$3 , by only typing "set $results"? Is it because IFS is set directly before it?

@teeeeee: it doesn't split the array, it splits the string into the positional arguments. IFS is set to a newline as a delimiter.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk I see thanks. Is there a way to use your method but to also save the results to an array variable for later use in the script (like in jesse_b answer), but without using the readarray command (which is only available in bash)? i.e. something which would work with the basic "sh" shell?

@teeeeee: no because there are no arrays in POSIX sh

There are two fully-standards-compatible solutions, and they'll also be the fastest because they don't fork/exec more than necessary:
#!/bin/sh
docker exec mycontainer './script_in_container.sh' | {
  IFS= read -r X
  IFS= read -r Y
  IFS= read -r Z
  echo X=$X Y=$Y Z=$Z
}

(you can omit the IFS= prefix if you don't care about stripping initial whitespace) and
#!/bin/sh
Z="$(docker exec mycontainer './script_in_container.sh')"
X="${Z%%$'\n'*}"
Z="${Z#*$'\n'}"
Y="${Z%%$'\n'*}"
Z="${Z#*$'\n'}"
echo X=$X Y=$Y Z=$Z

%% is "remove matches recursively from the end", # is "remove one match from the start`, so removing all matches of [newline, anything] removes every line but the first, and removing one match of [anything, newline] removes the first line.
The $'\n' spelling is new in POSIX.1-2024, and not universally available; you can spell it as
'
'

(so,
X="${Z%%'
'*}"

) to increase your compatibility range.
